# Android status bar color icons like ok google app

Tags: android, android-styles

if i change colorPrimaryDark from app style to white but color of icons on status bar doesn't reverse to black automatically so status bar icon can be visible,
basically i want status bar color like image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set statusBarColor to desired color and mark your status bar as light with `android:windowLightStatusBar` set to `true`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```